# Histogram of factor with labels on frequency bars

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Typically if I need to make a histogram with labels I will use `hist(rnorm(100),labels=TRUE)`. However if my data is factors then I need to use `plot(as.factor(c("a","a","b")))`. The issue with this is that `labels=TRUE` will not work with `plot`; **how do I fix this**?

I preferably want a solution without needing to load fancy packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually creating a bar plot in the second example

The following will work

```
 # your variable
 fact <- as.factor(c('a','a','b'))
 # 
 b <- plot(fact)
 text(x=b,y=c(table(fact)), label = c(table(fact)),xpd=TRUE,col='blue')
```

[image]

You could wrap it as function `plot.factor`.

```
plot.factor <- function(x ,..., label=TRUE) { 

  cc <- table(x)
  b <- barplot(cc,...)
  if (label){
    text(x = b, y = c(cc), label = c(cc), xpd = TRUE, col = 'blue')
  } 
return(invisible(b))
}


# Then

plot(fact) 
# would produce the same result
```