# Showing (value) labels in a histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, histogram, label

I have a variable in R with string value labels (occupation groups), but the actual values of the variable are numeric.

I would like to display the variable as a histogram, which would show the labels attached to certain numbers - for now, I've only been able to label the bars with number values (using "hist(occgroupsn, labels = TRUE)")
[Histogram with numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxp3k.png)

This is how I added the value labels (sorry for the messy code):

```
occgroups <- ordered(IscoGroups,
                 levels = c("01",
                            "02",
                            "03",
                            "11",
                            "12",
                            "13",
                            "14",
                            "21",
                            "22",
                            "23",
                            "24",
                            "25",
                            "26",
                            "31",
                            "32",
                            "33",
                            "34",
                            "35",
                            "41",
                            "42",
                            "43",
                            "44",
                            "51",
                            "52",
                            "53",
                            "54",
                            "61",
                            "62",
                            "63",
                            "71",
                            "72",
                            "73",
                            "74",
                            "75",
                            "81",
                            "82",
                            "83",
                            "91",
                            "92",
                            "93",
                            "94",
                            "95",
                            "96"),
                 labels = c("Commissioned armed forces officers"
                            , "Non-commissioned armed forces officers"
                            , "Armed forces occupations, other ranks"
                            , "Chief executives, senior officials and legislators"
                            , "Administrative and commercial managers"
                            , "Production and specialised services managers"
                            , "Hospitality, retail and other services managers"
                            , "Science and engineering professionals"
                            , "Health professionals"
                            , "Teaching professionals"
                            , "Business and administration professionals"
                            , "Information and communications technology professionals"
                            , "Legal, social and cultural professionals"
                            , "Science and engineering associate professionals"
                            , "Health associate professionals"
                            , "Business and administration associate professionals"
                            , "Legal, social, cultural and related associate professionals"
                            , "Information and communications technicians"
                            , "General and keyboard clerks"
                            , "Customer services clerks"
                            , "Numerical and material recording clerks"
                            , "Other clerical support workers"
                            , "Personal service workers"
                            , "Sales workers"
                            , "Personal care workers"
                            , "Protective services workers"
                            , "Market-oriented skilled agricultural workers"
                            , "Market-oriented skilled forestry, fishery and hunting workers"
                            , "Subsistence farmers, fishers, hunters and gatherers"
                            , "Building and related trades workers, excluding electricians"
                            , "Metal, machinery and related trades workers"
                            , "Handicraft and printing workers"
                            , "Electrical and electronic trades workers"
                            , "Food processing, wood working, garment and other craft and related trades workers"
                            , "Stationary plant and machine operators"
                            , "Assemblers"
                            , "Drivers and mobile plant operators"
                            , "Cleaners and helpers"
                            , "Agricultural, forestry and fishery labourers"
                            , "Labourers in mining, construction, manufacturing and transport"
                            , "Food preparation assistants"
                            , "Street and related sales and service workers"
                            , "Refuse workers and other elementary workers"))

occgroupsn <- as.numeric(occgroups)
hist(occgroupsn, labels = TRUE)
```

How to make them appear? Or should I do it in a different way?

EDIT: This is the same code with a smaller reproducible sample:

```
SampleVar <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4) 
SampleVarLabeled <- ordered(SampleVar,  
                    levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
                    labels = c("Commissioned armed forces officers" , 
                               "Noncommissioned armed forces officers" ,
                               "Armed forces, other ranks" , 
                               "Chief executives")) 
SampleVarLabeledn <- as.numeric(SampleVarLabeled) 
hist(SampleVarLabeledn, labels = TRUE)
```

Comment: is this answer a good response to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417760/histogram-of-factor-with-labels-on-frequency-bars

Comment: Your data is not reproducible. We do not have access to IscoGroups. You should use a smaller example data set for this question.

Comment: @Jealie thank you, but not exactly - that poster wants to get what I already do by using labels = TRUE for histogram

Comment: Hey @PLapointe, I created a smaller example data set now:

Comment: '
SampleVar <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)

SampleVarLabeled <- ordered(SampleVar,
                     levels = c("1",
                                "2",
                                "3",
                                "4"),
                     labels = c("Commissioned armed forces officers"
                                , "Noncommissioned armed forces officers"
                                , "Armed forces, other ranks"
                                , "Chief executives"))

SampleVarLabeledn <- as.numeric(SampleVarLabeled)
hist(SampleVarLabeledn, labels = TRUE)'

Comment: @AgataUtrecht The text labels are very long. How do you want them on the plot? Horizontally on top of bars like in your image? If so, they will splii over to other columns.

Comment: How they are in your barplot answer is fine, I will just need to adjust the text size a bit for my actual plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how I would do it. Since you are using the frequency version of `hist`, you can also use a `barplot` with counts. In your case, since the occupation names are very long, you should consider an horizontal barplot. It's easier to read. Here, I'm counting the frequency using `table`:

```
original_par <-par() #make a copy of your par
par(mar = c(5, 17, 2, 2))  #increase left  margin to 17
counts <- table(SampleVarLabeled)
barplot(counts, main="Occupation", xlab="Count",horiz=TRUE, las=1)

par() <- original_par #to go back to original par
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!